# Foreign Key Constraint Violation MS-SQL: useless error without details

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Violating a simple foreign key contraints in MS-SQL generates following useless error-message:

```
Error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_employee". The conflict occurred in database "AgentAndAgency", table "dbo.employee", column 'id'.
SQLState:  23000
ErrorCode: 547
```

Missing is the detail, which key is causing the foreign key contraint, so, e.g. PostgreSQL would say in the same situation:

```
Error: inserting into table employement violates foreign key contraint- „FK_employee“
Details: key (employee_id)=(958980) does not exist in table „employee“.
```

MS-SQL does not provide this information, which makes it completely useseless (I'm bulk-inserting thoundsands of records).

**Question**: how can I make MS-SQL tell me at least one missing key?

Comment: Does postgre identify *all* missing keys or just (an arbitrary) first one?

Comment: ...the arbitrary first one, and aborts the transaction. that is ok. MS-SQL does identify _none_  - no chance to find the error.

Comment: @Rémy Schumm, Consider using a staging table for your bulk inserts (without any indexes and constraints). After inserting the data, consider doing a `LEFT JOIN` with the corresponding table to eliminate the records which does not have `REFERENCING` values in the primary table.

Answer (score 3):

Because the data may contain *multiple* errors, the "identify one error, fix that and iterate" technique tends not to work out well.

No server, so far as I'm aware, will identify *all* missing keys - they terminate the work as soon as they've identified that *an* error has occurred<sup>1</sup> since the presence of just a *single* error may mean that the entire task needs to be aborted, rather than the data needing fixing.

To identify *all* of the errors, a better approach is to perform your bulk-insert into a staging table that doesn't have any constraints. Then write a query that `left join`s to the `employee` table and identifies *all* missing keys.

---

<sup>1</sup>Rather than potentially wasting resources by attempting to identify the complete set. But from a "relational-purist" perspective, that's what they *ought* to do - since we try to keep everything set-based, the errors ought to be *sets* too.

Comment: ok - but that was not my question. every Database I know will report the violating key - the first that is causing the error. MS-SQL does not. It makes it useless. What am I missing?

Comment: Hang on @Remy, just saying that SQL Server is useless isn't a question is it?

Comment: @RémySchumm - like I say though, that encourages the "fix one error at a time" technique, which for *sets* is not an optimal way of working. From a *purist* perspective, they ought to identify *all* errors, but no database system does that because it may be potentially wasteful, and they do not know that you purpose is to (eventually) identify *all* errors.

Comment: @RémySchumm - and your question appears to be "how do I get SQL Server to tell me at least one missing key" and the answers we're providing do perform that task. The fact that the answer is "by not triggering an error in the first place, and not acting like *via an error message* is the only sensible means of doing so" doesn't mean that they're *wrong*.

Comment: @TDPotts no, that was not my question - I just said the error message in this case is useless. the question is: how do I make MS-SQL give me a useful error-message?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the update, do a `SELECT` from your update data `WHERE employee_id NOT IN (SELECT employee_id FROM employee)`

Should give you the list of missing employee_ids

Comment: :-) I dont want to import my data in a temp. table before inserting it into a real one just to check relational integrity. that's the point of using a relational database, and the database should show me the errors...